# Apply stylesheet like margin and color to a paragraph in python

Tags: python, ms-word, styling, docx, python-docx

I am new to python can anyone tell me how to apply style-sheet to a paragraph. i have added the code like this

```
import re
from docx import Document # for Word document 
from docx.text import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

document.add_paragraph('My first paragraph')
```

But when i am trying to make this paragraph red and also apply margin-left:20px using its style attribute its not working

Comment: import re
from docx import Document # for Word document
from docx.text import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
import reportlab 
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH # For adding the Alignmant to the paragraph

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph('My first paragraph',style='BodyText', breakbefore=False, jc='left')

p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
document.save("MyDoc.docx")

But its whowing me this error 
TypeError: add_paragraph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'breakbefore'

Comment: put that in the question in a code block. Its unreadable like this

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, several problems here.

- No need to import re as far as I can see, that's the regular expressions library and not used here.
- reportlab is for PDF documents. You can't just arbitrarily apply styles from reportlab to a python-docx document and expect it to work. They're two completely different libraries.
- The Paragraph class is not meant to be instantiated directly, so no need to import it.

To do what you describe you can do the following:

Create a Word document having the paragraph style you want, say 'Red Indent', remove all the content from the document, and save it as 'styled.docx'

Then:

```
document = Document('styled.docx')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('My first paragraph')
paragraph.style = 'RedIndent'
```

Note the space between 'Red' and 'Indent' is removed when applying the style from python-docx.

Comment: Hey scanny
As per your above mention comment i applied the same thing 
but its not working, its just appending the newly added text at the bottom of doc file without any color.

Comment: Try with 'RedIndent' instead. I should have removed the space between the words.